# Conda PackagesNotFoundError

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, conda, environment

I wanted to create new env in Conda with specific version of Python so I can download a software (Busco) that only works with this python version.
i used the command

```
conda create -n envname  python=3.3.0

but i got this error msg :

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
current channels:

  - python=3.3.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

and more current channels like this 
can you please tell me what to do

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that version 3.3 of Python is no longer hosted on the conda-forge channel or the bioconda channel.  You can still get it on the anaconda channel using:

```
conda create -n envname python=3.3.0 -c anaconda
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer  i created env using your command but when i wanted to download the software using this command : conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge busco=4.0.5   i got this error message :  busco=4.0.5 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.3.0

Comment: @MejaitAnouar, why do you think busco needs python 3.3, a version that reached its end of life in september 2017? The version `4.0.5` you are installing seems to support all current python versions.

Comment: you're right , i guess i made a mistake , still i don't know now how to download it this new version  i alwayse have error msgs , actually  i have the version 2 in Busco , in other environement and when i create new environement  to download the new version it dosent work , also when i try to update Busco vesrion it  didn't wokr also , i'm soo confused now , i ll be so thankfuk for your help